# VS2012 new project from existing files

Tags: visual-studio-2012

When you Create New C# Project From Existing Files, the dialogue has a dropdown called "Output Type" giving choices of "Console Application", "Windows Application" and "Class Library".  None of them seem appropriate for a web application. What does the Output Type actually do and what should I select for a web app?

Comment: what sku of visual studio are you using?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio 2012 do you have exactly?

Comment: It's Version 11.0.51106.01 Update 1

Comment: And why the mark down?  If you can't ask people here how to get through MS's ridiculous UI's then where? Others may have similar concerns and, if this is answered, it will help them too.

Comment: @Craig: for starters at StackOverflow, because that is targeted at programmer topics more than SuperUser. Also, downvotes are anonymous, so if no one left a comment, you'll never know. It happens. You can still edit and improve your question, however. It can help at times.

Comment: Thanks, but I deliberately didn't put this question on StackOverflow because it's more of a user than a coding issue. I guess you just can't win, you get a bollocking whichever way you turn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output type only tells the project creation wizard what you want approximately. If there is no exact fit, you can still take the closest choice. For example, is your "web app" supposed to be deployed as `.exe` or `.dll` (may not be *named* with that extension). Choose the closest and then customize the project further to your needs.

The given templates just provide an outline for the project. I always end up customizing *some* aspect and I don't see why this would be discouraged. So just customize away.

Comment: A web app will generally be a dll (in my experience). So which selection produces which output? This is what gets me about MS UI's and documentation, they assume you already know, they don't give enough hints.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: since VS2k5, projects for websites/webapps have become more an more nebulous. in reality, the site "project" is just a folder with some files in it. there is no .XXproj file, or any other metadata to glue the site objects together, other than the web.config. you might as well just create a blank web project and add all the files afterward, since there isn't any kind of import process. in fact, if you have a site project pointing to a root folder, and add a file to that folder in windows explorer, it will automatically appear in the project in solution explorer.

Comment: @FrankThomas, that is true of websites, but not for web applications. Web applications contain compiled code and include a project file.